# Why am I getting an error when I compile with custom modules?

Tags: azerothcore

Can anyone help me with this one.

I git cloned a new azetothcore.

Added custom mods like Luna, anti cheat, AH bot, etc... all from azerothcore

Then add build file, and attempt to compile, but I keep getting errors
[[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was related to Linux... I compiled on windows OS, and it worked fine